# Windows 7 wireless suddenly doesn't work anymore

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router, connection

***EDIT***

Nevermind, probme seems to be the router, tried resetting it to factory defaults, doesn't help either. It's a WRT54GS v5.1 Linksys router

***END EDIT***

For some reason my laptop with windows 7 can't connect to my router properly anmore.

The router is a Linksys with a mac-address filter. The laptop has always had good connection on it.

I've reset the router, tried updating drivers, done diagnostics, troubleshooter, etc, I get results like this:

> problem with wireless adapter or access point
>
> a network cable is not properly
>   plugged in or may be broken
>
> the default gateway is not available

Sometimes the tray-icon shows connection with excellent signal strenght, only when opening the network dialog box it shows a warning sign on the connection, and the internet is either still not working or incredibly slow.

Also checked windows event logs, they just say it can't connect, no response from router received, etc ...

I've seem to been through all the normal windows help tools and they don't help. If I plug it into the router directly it works fine though but that's not very usefull on a laptop.

What's the best way to figure out where the problem really lies? Or does anybody have any ideas on what else to try?

Edit:
This is the only thing that seems to really point me in a direction in the event logs of Diagnostics-Networking:

> Profile match: Success
>
> Pre-associatoin: Success
>
> Association: Fail
>
> Security and authentication: Not
>   started
>
> Association status: Fail 0x00038002
>
> Association reason code: 0x00000002

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall the network card driver. Also try "repair" on the network once it's reinstalled.

Comment: Done this through device manager, no effect. What do you mean by repair? Where do I find this option?

Comment: I tried the repair automatically in the CP->Troubleshooting->Network/Internet->Network Adapter box, but also no effect

Answer (score 1):

Is this happens to all Wireless networks probably the problem with you NIC , if only happens to this router it may some wrong configuration with you router

Try Reinstalling the NIC drivers
Make sure to install the manufacturers NIC driver release not a default driver provided by windows

Comment: Okay, just tried connecting with my desktop wich used to connect with a USB, and it also could not connect, so it must be the router, but how to find the problem?

Comment: some times may be some one has played up with your router ;) , try resetting the settings to default . whats your router model ?

Comment: WRT54GS v5.1, I went to linksys helpdesk and they just said it's out of warranty and that I had to call they phone service, what rip off. I'm gonna try the rest now, hopefully I can get it back working again.

Comment: great good luck with it !

Comment: Resetted to factory defaults, no effect.

Comment: Is it possible that the router's wireless capabilities is interferred because it's in between other electrical devices such as TV, surround set, PS3, ...?

Comment: Also, the original computer that was here first is gone, could that have served as host PC or something?